# Formatting Last Row in tableview in JavaFx

Tags: java, css, javafx-8, fxml

I need to format the last row in a tableview in JavaFX through the css, if it not possible in CSS then how can do that in the code.

Comment: there's the :last-child selector

Comment: @Goombah are you sure is it javafx css property????

Comment: No, my bad. It's not. What about a classname for the last row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();

// ...

PseudoClass lastRow = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("last-row");

table.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Item>() {
    @Override
    public void updateIndex(int index) {
        super.updateIndex(index);
        pseudoClassStateChanged(lastRow, 
            index >= 0 && index == table.getItems().size() - 1);
    }
});
```

(obviously replace `Item` with your actual model class) and now in an external css file:

```css
.table-row-cell:last-row {
    /* styles for last row here... */
}

.table-row-cell:last-row .table-cell {
    /* styles for cells in last row here, if needed */
}
```

SSCCE:

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewStyleLastRow extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(column("Item", Item::nameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Value", Item::valueProperty));

        PseudoClass lastRow = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("last-row");
        table.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Item>(){
            @Override
            public void updateIndex(int index) {
                super.updateIndex(index);
                pseudoClassStateChanged(lastRow, index >=0 && index == table.getItems().size() - 1);
            }
        });

        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 25 ; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i, rng.nextInt(200)));
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(table);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style-last-row.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, Property<T>> prop) {
        TableColumn<S, T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> prop.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public final java.lang.String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setName(final java.lang.String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }


        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with style-last-row.css:

```css
.table-row-cell:last-row {
    -fx-background: #707070 ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @James_D, Great Answer.